# String variable assignment doesn't work in grads

Tags: grads

Trying to assign string variable like,
`mon = "jan"`
but it returns `Syntax error : Invalid Operand`

I'm on window opengrads.

```
ga-> mon = "jan"
Syntax Error:  Invalid Operand
  'jan' not a variable or function name
  Error ocurred at column 1
DEFINE error:  Invalid expression.
```